# Gauge chart in JavaFX 2

Tags: charts, javafx-2

Is there a way to produce a simple Gauge chart in JavaFX 2? It seems like it's not available in the `javafx.scene.chart` package... (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm)

Something like this: www.bscdesigner.com/kpi_designer_manual/gauge-chart.gif

or this: www.coresystems.ch/wp-content/uploads/files_downloads/help/country_package/manual/en/widget_04_sample_gauge_en.png

**EDIT:** this is the design it should approach: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/274249/screenshot_score_meters.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

too late for you but might be interesting as a reference.

***Medusa*** has all the configurable gauges you could imagine: https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa

and a tuto: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-992746

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JFXtras 2 project](http://jfxtras.org/), they got you covered.

Comment: Thank you! I had a look to the available gauges in JFXtras, but the only radial gauges are these ones: http://tinypic.com/r/2v9xik8/6. They are not really what I am looking for, because they don't fit well in the design and don't represent colors green, orange, red. I need something much simpler, like in the links I provided above...

Comment: Thanks. Could you extend your question to point and critical features and design elements?

Comment: OK, I added a screenshot of the design I should follow.